# How do I find out why my computer is turning on by itself?

Tags: linux, boot

My laptop sometimes turns on in the middle of the night for no apparent reason. The only mechanism I know of for this is Wake on LAN, but I have never deliberately enabled that, and I can't see any settings in my BIOS to enable it or disable it, and I can't think of anything on my home network that would send a WoL packet.

My laptop is a PC Specialist Optimus from 2012, under the hood it is a Clevo W150ER. I am running Kubuntu 22.04.

Answer (score 0):

Many options can cause a laptop to automatically turn on. among these are bios settings that restore the laptop to a previous state
some bios-es have option to switch on on set times and days (unlikely for consumer laptops to have this rare option, but a look around in the bios wont hurt)

But I suspect your laptop not being really switched off, more likely I suspect you use the suspend or a deep sleep option (closed the lid or pressed the power button shortly) and Linux will put the computer in a certain type of sleep.
And from here, either a mouse movement detection, keyboard press or an external usb device that might trigger the wake up? usb wake up might be an option within the bios, or you could take a look at your Kubuntu install if its using a sleep state instead of true sleep.

If you truly are sure you've instructed Linux to shutdown, and the bios has no option turned on to wake from sleep. Its an older machine by now, maybe a closer look at the power button hardware, and maybe a little cleanup to make sure its not a intermittent button press due to ambient temperature changes or static.

Comment: Thanks! I can't see anything in the BIOS about waking up on LAN, USB, on a timer, or anything else. I have only observed the behaviour when the laptop is fully shut down (from the start menu, or whatever KDE calls that), because I come downstairs and find it's on waiting for me to enter the encryption password. It's possible it also happens when it's sleeping, but I wouldn't notice because it would just put itself back to sleep 12 minutes later :) I had wondered about a power button hardware fault, giving that a clean up is not a bad idea.

Comment: When you are finished using your computer do you shut down, sleep or hibernate?

Comment: @Mastaxx Usually sleep, sometimes shut down, never hibernate. As I said above, I've only observed the mysterious turning on when the laptop has been fully shut down.